# How to pause/resume/cancel my download request in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am downloading a file using Alamofire download with progress but i have no idea how to pause / resume / cancel the specific request.

```
@IBAction func downloadBtnTapped() {

 Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/stream/100", destination: destination)
     .progress { (bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) in
         println(totalBytesRead)
     }
     .response { (request, response, _, error) in
         println(response)
     }
}


@IBAction func pauseBtnTapped(sender : UIButton) {        
    // i would like to pause/cancel my download request here
}
```

Answer (score 36):

Keep a reference to the request created in `downloadBtnTapped` with a property, and call `cancel` on that property in `pauseBtnTapped`.

```
var request: Alamofire.Request?

@IBAction func downloadBtnTapped() {
 self.request = Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/stream/100", destination: destination)
}

@IBAction func pauseBtnTapped(sender : UIButton) {
  self.request?.cancel()
}
```

Comment: Does this cancel all request?

Comment: `request.cancel()` doesn't guarantee to cancel the request immediately. This makes progress block to be called after the cancel. Is there any built-in way to check if the cancel/suspend is called?

Comment: Pausing is request?.suspend() OR request?. cancel() ?

Comment: From offical docs: **`suspend()`: Suspends the underlying task and dispatch queue. `resume()`: Resumes the underlying task and dispatch queue. If the owning manager does not have.** So suspend pauses a request.

Answer (score 24):

`request.cancel()` will cancel the download progress. If you want to pause and continue, you can use:

```
var request: Alamofire.Request?

@IBAction func downloadBtnTapped() {
 self.request = Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://yourdownloadlink.com", destination: destination)
}

@IBAction func pauseBtnTapped(sender : UIButton) {
  self.request?.suspend()
}

@IBAction func continueBtnTapped(sender : UIButton) {
  self.request?.resume()
}

@IBAction func cancelBtnTapped(sender : UIButton) {
  self.request?.cancel()
}
```

Comment: what is the difference of suspend and cancel ?  is suspend more similiar with pause ?