# Http request using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to send HTTP request in my App. I'm using a TabBarViewController, In first view's ViewDidLoad, I send a request. Also in ViewWillDisappear, I send another request. However, I found it behave unexpected when I changing the tabs.

```
func sendHttpCommand(parameter: NSDictionary) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: (parameter as! [String: AnyObject]))
             .response {
                 request, response, data, error in
                 print(request)
             }
}

viewDidLoad() {
    let dict: NSDictionary = ["value": 0]
    sendHttpCommand(dict)
}

viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    let dict: NSDictionary = ["value": 1]
    sendHttpCommand(dict)
}
```

When I switching the tabs, in **NORMAL CASE**, my console will print out

```
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=0})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=1})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=0})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=1})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=0})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=1})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=0})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=1})
```

However, when I switching the tabs **fast enough**, my console will print out

```
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=0})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=1})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=1})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=0})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=0})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=1})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=1})
Optional(NSMutableURLRequest {URL: xxxxx/value=0})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

the alamofire requests are executed async.

Read here to understand asyncs and syncs:
[Difference between dispatch_async and dispatch_sync on serial queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822700/difference-between-dispatch-async-and-dispatch-sync-on-serial-queue)

You can cancel your alamofire request when you change the tab and the request is not finished. For this you need an Alamofire Manager.

Comment: How can I make the request in order? I tried to use `dispatch_group`. However, i seems not working. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100847/checking-for-multiple-asynchronous-responses-from-alamofire-and-swift)

Comment: you have to call the next request in your response handler. Or use a delegate and fire it in your response handler to start the next request. You can also cancel your request if the user changes the tab http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305707/how-to-pause-resume-cancel-my-download-request-in-alamofire